# Android Admob - How to declare AdActivity in Manifest

Tags: android, admob

I try to create simple example for AdMob but I failed. This is my source code

AdMobActivity

```
public class AdMobActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         ads:adUnitId="myId"
         ads:adSize="BANNER"
         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="my.ad.mob"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="9"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".AdMobActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

I use AdMob 4.3.1 and for Android target=android-13

When I try to execute project, in place where my add needs to be is message: "You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges". So where is my mistake here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AdActivity must have these config changes:

`keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize`

Comment: I try this and now in that place is a black screen, there is nothing (I only see TextView witch I add)...

<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/hello"/>
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="id"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

Comment: Did you replace `id` with your actual adUnitId?  If not, you'll get a warning in the logs saying "Invalid Request".

Comment: In log I have this: 
onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory.) and my id is good.

Comment: If you get that then everything is fine. If you wish to see ads while debugging, just add a testing device to your adview element and that's it.

Comment: It's working now thanks, but this is only testing adds is it means that when I remove    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" I will get real addons on real davice because on emulator I don't get adds without ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"?

Comment: Yes, usually you cannot get real ads in emulator. Just relax, if you see the tests ads your users will see real ads.

Comment: OK, Thanks, now I am relaxed :)

Answer (score 1):

And full answer for those using modern adMob from Google Mobile Services should be:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

(note, that `android:name` changed)