# Android Admob won't run?

Tags: android, admob

This is the AdMob project i'm trying to compile but i'm not having a lot of luck. I have a publisher id from the AdMob website and everything too. The problem is when i run it crashes right away. I'll post my code and log cat for you. Thanks!

Heres a link to the log cat:

http://imageshack.us/f/29/z5t.png/

This is what my MainActivity.java file looks like:

```
package com.example.testingitgood;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    AdView adView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create an ad.
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

        // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
        // until the ad is loaded.
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        layout.addView(adView);

        // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
        // get test ads on a physical device.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);

        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is what my activity_main.xml file looks like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is what my AndroidManifest.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testingitgood"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testingitgood.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: Do a project clean, am make sure the Admob library is included in the BuildPath.

Comment: @AndyRes yes I do have the AdMob Library included.
http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/9343/g70w.png

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you are creating the AdView in the layout then re-creating it in your activity. Try parsing the object you created in your XML to the object you are creating in your activity.

```
AdView ad =(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
ad.loadAd(new AdRequest().addTestDevice("<test device id goes here>"));
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error while opening. :/. Am I only suppose to have the adview in one or the other?

Comment: Mhmm :/

Like most things, the adview should be 'declared' in the XML and given an id. Then in the activity, we create an empty adview and assign the one we created in the XML by calling the ID we gave it.

Not sure why this isn't working..

Answer (score 0):

A common problem is not declaring an ad acitivty in your manifest file... [Android Admob - How to declare AdActivity in Manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214308/android-admob-how-to-declare-adactivity-in-manifest) see if this answer helps.